# How to use PHP to access MSSQL on windows7

Tags: php, sql-server

What's the best way to:

1. access a MSSQL db (running 2012 locally, 2005+2008 on LAN)
2. on a win 7 64bit
3. using PHP?

I'd like to use the MSSQL functions in PHP, like mssql_query and mssql_connect, rather than an ADODB.Connection or PDO.

It sounds simple, but I've had a bit of trouble... I figured WAMP was a safe bet, but apparently the newer versions don't contain the MSSQL extension. Messed about a bit with ntwdblib.dll to no avail.

Anybody running the described setup, or know of a good tutorial for setting it up?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Have you had a look in here [How to get WAMP to work with MSSQL](http://forum.ragezone.com/f724/get-wamp-work-mssql-673301/)? There's also Microsoft's own [SQL Server Driver for PHP (aka SQLSRV)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/ff657782.aspx).

Comment: Yep, tried it with no luck (crashed my comp with a BSOD), but you've made me persevere :)

For anybody in the same situation, follow the directions here: http://forum.ragezone.com/f724/get-wamp-work-mssql-673301/

but with the following modifications:

a) the link to ntwdblib.dll is dead. Try: http://www.dlldll.com/ntwdblib.dll_download.html

b) if you're running a newer (64bit) version of WAMP, you might not have a folder called wamp\bin\apache\apache2.2.11\bin

Try: wamp\bin\apache\apache2.2.22\bin


Lastly, check if you've got mssql, using:

Thanks for the great help guys!

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I've run into this problem before as well. You would think default drivers would exist from php to mssql and be easy to install, but for some bizarre reason they're not.

My workplace uses FreeTDS to make it work.  Try these links for more info:

- http://www.peceny.de/misc/freetds.html
- http://www.freetds.org/
- http://docs.moodle.org/22/en/Installing_MSSQL_for_PHP#Using_FreeTDS_on_Windows

Hope that helps.